# How to zoom correctly a mandelbrot?

Tags: php, mandelbrot

I'm trying to zoom into my mandelbrot and I read this question: [How to perform Simple Zoom into Mandelbrot Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381675/how-to-perform-simple-zoom-into-mandelbrot-set?rq=1)  but I have difficult to understand it and it doesn't work. When I calculate the new real and complex number like so:

```
double Re_factor = (MaxRe-MinRe)/(ImageWidth-1);
double Im_factor = (MaxIm-MinIm)/(ImageHeight-1);

double newMinRe = MinRe + (Re_factor* x1);
double newMaxRe = MinRe + (Re_factor* x2);
double newMinIm = MinIm + (Im_factor* y1);
double newMaxIm = MinIm + (Im_factor* y2);
```

the new mandelbrot is a bit distorted in both axis? What is wrong? Here is an example: http://www.phpdevpad.de/index.php?id=190.

Comment: That interface just breaks when I try to interact with it. Could you please post a page with just the Mandelbrot Set?

Comment: When you hit immediately submit does it work? The change the bounding box and click "zoom in". It works for me with Opera?

Comment: Is it possible that it appears distorted because of the viewable region you are displaying it in? I would think the y axis would be taller.

Comment: I don't have any idea. I use exactly the given formula?! Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: @ethrbunny: You are right. It's because aspect ratio is 16:10. Make an answer i accept you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The display area is distorted (y axis is not large enough). Your equations are fine.